# Using Netbeans for PHP, any remote system explorer?

Tags: php, eclipse, netbeans, ide

Alright so I currently develop on a remote server and use putty for an SSH connection to deal with SVN. I develop with Eclipse PDT only due to the fact that it has the remote system explorer, so I don't have to actually have the files on my local machine to edit them, which is great.

Netbeans is my IDE of choice, and I've been googling for a while trying to figure out how I can possibly make this work with a netbeans project. I can't seem to find any plugins/any statement discussing the possibility of a future plugin/implementation to incorporate this.

Has anyone successfully accomplished this? Are there perhaps any standalone clients I can use to achieve this?

Thanks guys.

Comment: Why don't you check out the project to work on it, since you're using SVN anyway?

Comment: You can look at some of the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390321/working-on-a-remote-php-project-ubuntu-server-via-eclipse-netbeans-or-any-othe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need plugins with Netbeans for Svn (Git requires a plugin), you just have to click on "Team" -> "Subversion" on the Menu bar on top.

In "Window" -> "Services" you can browse some stuff like databases or team server too.

Comment: @MiPnamic, Is there any way to browse remote files like in dreamweaver?

Answer (score 0):

There is always the option to set up netbeans to browse a remote folder via ftp ( http://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/ftp_support_added )

You could also use `sshfs` to create a local mount of the remote folders/files.

I do agree that you should probably be using svn/git/whatever to develop locally and then push to the live site when ready instead.

Note: Netbeans does svn/cvs built in, but git requires the third party nbgit plugin which is still in it's infancy.

Comment: Is there any way to browse remote files like in dreamweaver?