# Working on a remote PHP project (Ubuntu Server) via Eclipse, Netbeans or any other IDE

Tags: php, windows, ubuntu

I am wokring on a PHP project, which is located on an Ubuntu server to which I have SSH access.

Sometimes I code in Ubuntu and sometimes in Windows (mostly Ubuntu).
Do you have any idea how to connect to the project on the server and edit the files. I searched the net, got some ideas like using SSHFS, but I want something which works both on Linux and Windows.

I also found Eclipse Remote System Explorer, but I think it is not that stable and might cause problems (correct me if I am wrong).

Basically I (like) code in Eclipse, but I can move to Netbeans or any other good (but Free) IDEs, if I have to.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Aptana Studio 3](http://aptana.com/) has everything you need

- ssh w/ built in terminal
- sftp (connect FTP through SSH)
- Eclipse Based
- GIT/SVN support
- PHP Support
- [etc...](http://aptana.com/products/studio3)

Related to your comment:

- [How Connect to remote host from Aptana Studio 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201939/how-connect-to-remote-host-from-aptana-studio-3)
- http://vimeo.com/aptana

Comment: @SeanJA: What's you issue with formatting HTML and PHP nicely? Maybe you just can handle an IDE :)

Comment: For me, too. I never had an issue. You just have to type correctly or set up the formatting settings to your defaults.

Comment: @Phill Pafford: This sounds like what I want, but can you give me some clues to start? Like how to set up SSH with Aptana? Thanks.

Comment: @Kau-Boy Never had problems with Netbeans... but when I right click and select the "format" option in Aptana it screws up everything that was screwed up already, but worse (this is old ul > table > table > table > ul > table layout).

Comment: @Kau-Boy I would gladly give it another try... do you have a settings export lying around somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

At my company each developer has a windows PC to work from with a linux dev VM that mirrors production's setup. The linux servers have a samba share setup to the `/var/www` directory. There are two common workflows we follow.

1. The developer checks out the code repo to their local PC. They use Netbeans (previously Eclipse) to edit the files and an IDE feature copies the edited file to the webserver via samba.

   - Pro: fast
   - Con: webserver can get out of sync, only one way syncing: windows -> VM
2. The developer checks out the code repo to the samba folder. They open the code from the IDE and edit from there.

   - Pro: two way syncing, can edit from server if need be, can use any editor/IDE
   - Con: slow

We ran for a while under setup 2, but quickly found that it was far too slow for us so most use setup 1. The only exceptions are remote teams that find it easier to connect directly to the VMs.

Answer (score 1):

I use eclipse with Aptana. There you can easily use the build in FTP support to connect to the server.

Another solution would be mouting the server directory to your PC. On Windows systems you can use something like [WebDrive](http://www.southrivertech.com/products/webdrive/winindex.html).

Answer (score 1):

I use [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) with [Tramp](http://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/) plug-in.

Comment: Although many people love Emacs, but I prefer to use a more advanced IDE.

Comment: @Ako: Be careful when you say "more advanced" in this context :-)

Comment: I am sorry, I don't want to walk on Emacs's tail. I know what kind of IDE it is, but I am not very comfortable with it. Thanks, and sorry again.